# Material UI upload button showing no file chosen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use one of the MU upload buttons with ReactJS, with the exact code from the official page (4th button, with the icon): https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#upload-button
I've imported all the needed dependencies, and my React code for this button is as follows:

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import PhotoCamera from "@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera";

import "./SignUp.css";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }
}));

function SignUp() {
  const classes = useStyles();

return (
      <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
            <IconButton
              color="primary"
              aria-label="upload picture"
              component="span"
            >
              <PhotoCamera />
            </IconButton>
        </label>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However I'm seeing this fairly ugly "Choose file" - no file chosen button. I should only be seeing the camera icon at the bottom.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Vap.png)
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please include your code for rendering the file input element (i.e. the one with id of `icon-button-file`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had forgotten to add this piece of code: 
 input: {
    display: "none"
  }

This goes into the useStyles function.

Answer (score -4):

This might help you [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-star-6r0gm) in same way.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import PhotoCamera from "@material-ui/icons/PhotoCamera";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IconButton>
        <PhotoCamera />
      </IconButton>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```